MediaPipe Landmarks to BVH
I am doing a project about transferring the image taken from the camera to animation. I want to transfer the body pose movements I detected with Mediapipe to the blender environment as animation. I will make this transfer in bvh format. But how will I calculate the rotation rotations of the desired joints in the bvh file format?  With Mediapipe, I can only see the x,y,z coordinates of the joints. Can anyone who has information on this subject help?
hierarchy
ROOT hip
{
    OFFSET 0.000000 2.093389 0.000000
    CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
    JOINT spine1
    {
        OFFSET 0.000000 0.221812 0.055651
        CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
        JOINT spine2
        {
            OFFSET 0.000000 0.259166 0.010859
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            JOINT spine3
            {
                OFFSET 0.000000 0.259166 0.006787
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT shoulder.L
                {
                    OFFSET 0.144217 0.158309  0.020963
                    CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
                    JOINT upperarm.L
                    {
                        OFFSET 0.233226 -0.001289 0.020344
                        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                        JOINT lowerarm.L
                        {
                            OFFSET 0.569278 0.000000 0.028651
                            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                            JOINT hand.L
                            {
                                OFFSET 0.530662 0.000000 -0.028651
                                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                                End Site
                                {
                                    OFFSET 0.183393 0.000000 0.000000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                JOINT neck
                {
                    OFFSET 0.000000 0.259166 -0.017645
                    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                    JOINT head
                    {
                        OFFSET 0.000000 0.206271 -0.095711
                        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                        End Site
                        {
                            OFFSET 0.000000 0.475892 -0.060541
                        }
                    }
                }
                JOINT shoulder.R
                {
                    OFFSET -0.144217 0.158309 0.020963
                    CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
                    JOINT upperarm.R
                    {
                        OFFSET -0.233226 -0.001289 0.020344
                        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                        JOINT lowerarm.R
                        {
                            OFFSET -0.569278 0.000000 0.028651
                            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                            JOINT hand.R
                            {
                                OFFSET -0.530662 0.000000 -0.028651
                                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                                End Site
                                {
                                    OFFSET -0.183393 0.000000 0.000000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JOINT thigh.L
    {
        OFFSET 0.206315 -0.157451 0.040530
        CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
        JOINT shin.L
        {
            OFFSET 0.000000 -0.928808 -0.019702
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            JOINT foot.L
            {
                OFFSET 0.000000 -0.805280 0.036120
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT toe.L
                {
                    OFFSET 0.037360 -0.175911 -0.243095
                    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                    End Site
                    {
                        OFFSET 0.031738 0.000000 -0.206517
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    JOINT thigh.R
    {
        OFFSET -0.206315 -0.157451 0.040530
        CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
        JOINT shin.R
        {
            OFFSET 0.000000 -0.928808 -0.019702
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            JOINT foot.R
            {
                OFFSET 0.000000 -0.805280 0.036120
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT toe.R
                {
                    OFFSET -0.037360 -0.175911 -0.243095
                    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                    End Site
                    {
                        OFFSET -0.031738 0.000000 -0.206517
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#The code I use to calculate rotation
  spine1_rotation = (hip_x + spine1_x , hip_y + spine1_y, hip_z + spine1_z)
                    spine2_rotation = (spine1_x + spine2_x, spine1_y + spine2_y, spine1_z + spine2_z)                    
                    spine3_rotation = (spine2_x + spine3_x, spine2_y + spine3_y, spine2_z + spine3_z)
                    
                    shoulder_L_rotation = (spine3_x + shoulder_L.x , spine3_y + shoulder_L.y, spine3_z + shoulder_L.z)
                    upperarm_L_rotation = (shoulder_L.x + upperarm_L.x, shoulder_L.y + upperarm_L.y, shoulder_L.z + upperarm_L.z)
                    lowerarm_L_rotation = (upperarm_L.x + lowerarm_L.x , upperarm_L.y + lowerarm_L.y, upperarm_L.z + lowerarm_L.z)
                    hand_L_rotation = (lowerarm_L.x + hand_L.x , lowerarm_L.y + hand_L.y, lowerarm_L.z + hand_L.z)
                    

When calculating the rotation of the joints as seen in the BVH file format, I added the coordinates of the interconnected joints and the skeleton did not move in any way.

please do not tag unrelated technologies. OpenCV is not related to your question.
